# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute (...) when iterate over a dictionary of sets

Tags: python-2.7, graph, pycharm, attributeerror

I'm trying to remove a node from an undirected graph represented by his adjacency list but I'm receiving an error that I can't understand.

Example of a ugraph:

```
g1 = {0: set([1]), 1: set([0, 2]), 2: set([1, 3]), 3: set([2]), 4: {5, 6}, 5: {4}, 6: {}}
```

Function that I'm creating:

```
def remove_node(ugraph, node):
    """
    :param ugraph: An undirected graph
    :param node: The node that we want to remove
    :return: The undirected graph minus one node :)
    """

    try:
        del ugraph[node]
    except KeyError:
        print "The node is not in the graph" 

    for key in ugraph.keys():
        ugraph[key] = ugraph[key].difference(set([node]))

    return ugraph
```

And this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juan/PycharmProjects/AlgorithmicThinking_week2/resilence.py", line 46, in <module>
    print remove_node(g1, 1)
  File "/home/juan/PycharmProjects/AlgorithmicThinking_week2/resilence.py", line 42, in remove_node
    ugraph[key] = ugraph[key].difference(set([node]))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'difference'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The print  issue is for autocomplete. Please check my post again

Comment: The error message is exactly what it says: `upgraph` is a standard Python [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) object, and dict objects do not have an attribute (or method) like `difference`. Why do you think you need to call `.difference` on `upgraph`? If it were documented like that, there's something odd going on.

Comment: Looking at your actual `g1` object, I may spot the problem: the first few elements have values of type `set`, which do have a `difference` attribute. But the elements with key 6 has a value that is an (empty) dict, not a set.

Comment: I'm not calling  `difference` on ugraph but on the values of ugraph which are sets

Comment: I noticed; DSM and Rahul found the same issue I found in the mean time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these things is not like the other:

```
>>> g1 = {0: set([1]), 1: set([0, 2]), 2: set([1, 3]), 3: set([2]), 4: {5, 6}, 5: {4}, 6: {}}
>>> for key in g1: 
...     print key, g1[key], type(g1[key])
...
0 set([1]) <type 'set'>
1 set([0, 2]) <type 'set'>
2 set([1, 3]) <type 'set'>
3 set([2]) <type 'set'>
4 set([5, 6]) <type 'set'>
5 set([4]) <type 'set'>
6 {} <type 'dict'>
```

`{}` is an empty dict, not the empty set.  Use `set()` instead.

Comment: You are right but I dont understand why in some places I can use the set literal `{}` but in other places I need to use the set function call `set([])`

Comment: Because `{}` was used to refer to the empty dictionary before there *were* set literals.  (I wish the empty dict had been `{:}`, but can't be helped now.)  So we're stuck with `{}` being the empty dictionary and `{1}` being a set.

Comment: Thank you, my function  is ok. The problem was in `g1` as you said